# OutOfMemoryError and problems with ObservableList into ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I make an fxml file in javafx2.

I have a List of Person objects. The name of this List, is `Entries`. I have an ObservableList, `myObservableList`. Inside of this I want to put labels. Each label must contains a pair of image person and text of his name.
I write this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfEntries; i++){                               
    currentEntry = Entries.get(i);
    name=currentEntry.getName();                                  
    image1 = new Image("file:"+currentEntry.getIcon());                    
    imageView1= new ImageView();
    imageView1.setFitHeight(50);
    imageView1.setFitWidth(70);
    imageView1.setImage(image1);                       
    label = new Label(name, imageView1);
    label.setFont(new Font("serif", 32));                         
    myObservableList.add(label);                   
}
```

It works ok, but after a few puts of images the JVM gives me the below error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

This error comes from the code line      `image1 = new Image("file:"+currentEntry.getIcon());`

Finally, I want to put all elements of myObservableList into a ComboBox items. For this reason in Initialize method of java controller I write:

```
    myComboBox.setItems(myObservableList);

    ListCell<Label> buttonCell = new ListCell<Label>() {
         @Override protected void updateItem(Label item, boolean isEmpty) {
         super.updateItem(item, isEmpty);
            setText(item==null ? "" : item.getText());                 
        }
    };

    myComboBox.setButtonCell(buttonCell);
```

I am sure that I have not enough experience in javafx, and I do not know how must I handle for I have a combobox with pairs of icon and text in the same cell for all items.

I want to express my lot of thanks to Peter Duniho and PakkuDon for their help for improve English in my text.

Comment: How many items (approximately) in the list? How big, on average, are the images?

Comment: The list get the up load from a data base. I have a table “Person” with 8 columns. From this I read only 2 columns, the first name, and the file name (of icon of person).
May be approximately 200 persons names and icons. All this must up load to the combo box. Each icon is about 70Kb or 100kb.
I not know how I handle this.

Answer (score 2):

It is almost always a mistake to use a `Node` class as the data type for a `ComboBox` (or for any other control). You should use a class that represents the data only, and register a cell factory to configure how the data are displayed.

In your case, if you include the image in the data, you are likely to run into memory problems. Each image is likely to be represented in memory by a few megabytes. So your data class should hold the image name, and then you can use the cell in the combo box to create an image.

Here's some sample code to give you the idea:

Data class (Person.java):

```
public class Person {
    private final String name ;
    private final String imageFileName ;

    public Person(String name, String imageFileName) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public String getImageFileName() {
        return imageFileName ;
    }
}
```

UI code to create `ComboBox` from a `List<Person>`:

```
List<Person> entries = ... ; // populated from DB

ComboBox<Person> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().addAll(entries);

comboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Person>, ListCell<Person>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Person> call(ListView<Person> listCell) {

        return new ListCell<Person>() {
            private final ImageView = new ImageView();
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    File imageFile = new File(person.getImageFileName());
                    String imageUrl = imageFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
                    Image image = new Image(imageUrl, 70, 50, 
                        // preserve ratio
                        true, 
                        // smooth resizing
                        true,
                        // load in background
                        true);
                    imageView.setImage(image);
                    setText(person.getName());
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

You can use the same `ListCell` implementation for the `ComboBox`'s `buttonCell`.

The point here is that cells are only created for the visible cells, so the images are loaded "on demand" as the cells are displayed. Using the `Image` constructor that takes the width and height parameters also reduces the memory footprint, as the `Image` object can resize as it loads.

Finally, note that it's important to use the flag to load images in the background, which keeps the UI responsive. If you scroll quickly, you'll likely see some images not loaded for a brief while; the cells will repaint appropriately once the image becomes available.

Comment: dear James_D, 
Lot of thanks for your answer is very helpful for me.
I use java 7 and your line:

comboBox.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<Person>() {

is for java 8.
If you please to rewrite this for java 7?

Comment: You just have to convert the lambda to a `Callback` class (e.g. an anonymous inner class). I edited in line, I think it is correct but you should be able to fix any typos from here.

Comment: You are very fast and knowledge powerful person.
Really thank you for your kindness help.

Comment: The inner class return 'new ListCell<Person>()' alone works well, But all together, the code generates the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to libraryChildren.Person
at lbraryChildren.FXMLDocumentController$1$1.updateItem(FXMLDocumentController.java:132), line 132=return new ListCell<Person>()

Comment: You are putting `Person` objects in the list, right? Not `String`s.

Comment: My mistake. There was inside of  the text of the fχml file the tag

     <items>       
          <String fx:value="Item 1" />
          <String fx:value="Item 2" />
          <String fx:value="Item 3" /
      </items>

these automatically generated by scene builder.
the code of James_D works perfectly

Comment: dear friend all well finished. Thank you for your valuable help and I apologize for the inconvenience that I added to you with my many questions.
Mine was ultimately wrong. Your code is perfect.